# Error with Loop and recursive function

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a VbScript file that will read a text file that has a list of folder names in it.
From these folder names I need to create a second text file that prints out all the files with a specific extension.

I have used this code to do the second part of the task

```
Option Explicit 'force all variables to be declared
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Output.txt", ForWriting, True)
Call Recurse("C:\")
objTS.Close()

Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFolder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFile
    Dim objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'only proceed if there is an extension on the file.
        If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".") > 0) Then
            'If the file's extension is "pfx", write the path to the output file.
            If (LCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))) = ".exe") Then _
                objTS.WriteLine(objfile.Path)
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call Recurse(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried to put this in a loop but when I do I get a syntax error for this line Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)

Any help you can give me would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation of

> I have tried to *put this in a loop* but when I do I get a *syntax error*
>   for this line *Sub* Recurse(strFolderPath)

is that the structure of your resulting script looks like:

```
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   p = tsIn.ReadLine
   Sub Recurse(p)
   End Sub
   Call Recurse(p)
Loop
```

output:

```
cscript 27537600-B.vbs
..\27537600-B.vbs(3, 4) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error
```

VBScript does not allow nested Sub/Function definitions, especially in loops (you may get away with mixing simple statements and Sub/Function definitions in top-level code, but that's more a bug than a feature). If you re-structure the script like

```
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   p = tsIn.ReadLine
   Call Recurse(p)
Loop

Sub Recurse(p)
End Sub
```

you won't get a **syntax** error on the **Sub** line.